# Return PHP error handling with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page powered with PHP and AJAX, when a user submits one of my forms I check for errors in the getData.php script.

This example is if the user submits the form with the default value I'm wondering if there is a way to pass back those errors or trigger the AJAX to fire an error if the user commits on or if I need to do error handling before the AJAX call

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '_ajax/addData.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $("input").val('Info Here');
            $("form").hide();
            reloadInfo();
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$info = $_POST['info'];

if($info != 'Info Here') {
    $conn = mysqli_connect();
    $query = "INSERT INTO leads VALUES(0, '$companyName', 1, NOW(), 3)";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ('Error Could Not Query');

    $id = mysqli_insert_id($result);
    header("Location: http://localhost/manage/info.php?id=$id");

    mysqli_close($conn);
} else { 
    echo '<script>alert("Error");/script>'
}
```

**PART 2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript:

```
success: function (data) {
           if(!data.success) alert(data.errors); // Just for demonstration purposes
            $("input").val(data.errors);
            $("form").hide();
            reloadInfo();
        }
```

PHP:

```
header("Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf8");
if($info != 'Info Here') {
    $conn = mysqli_connect();
    $query = "INSERT INTO leads VALUES(0, '$companyName', 1, NOW(), 3)";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ('Error Could Not Query');

    $id = mysqli_insert_id($result);
    header("Location: http://localhost/manage/info.php?id=$id");

    mysqli_close($conn);
} else { 
    echo json_encode(array("success" => false,"error" => "Some random error happened"));
}
```

Comment: Well, this is a problem in the code logic. In PHP you need to echo the error if it failed. Clientside everything works.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

- `$companyName` is not defined anywhere
- You should use prepared statements instead of throwing data into your SQL query
- You should put your entire AJAX PHP code inside one [try..catch](http://php.net/exceptions) block
- At the end of your AJAX PHP code, write something some JSON
- I don't get why you are trying to redirect an AJAX call, usually you'd tell the client to do the redirect.

For example, I would write your PHP code like so:

```
try {

    if(!isset($_POST['info']))
        throw new Exception('Post info was not set');

    $info = $_POST['info'];

    if($info == 'Info Here')
        throw new Exception('Invalid value for info');

    $conn = mysqli_connect();
    if(!$conn)
        throw new Exception('Database connection failure');

    $companyName = '?????';

    $query = 'INSERT INTO leads VALUES(0, ?, 1, NOW(), 3)';
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($query);

    if(!$stmt)
        throw new Exception('Could not query database');

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $companyName);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    $id = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt);

    mysqli_close($conn);

    echo json_encode(array(
        'success' => true,
        'new_id'  => $id,
    ));

}catch(Exception $ex){

    echo json_encode(array(
        'success' => false,
        'reason'  => $ex->getMessage(),
    ));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Alternate Approach**

**HTML:** place this paragraph tag where you want to display an error.

```
<p id="display_error"></p>
```

**Ajax success call:** change your Ajax code bit like...

```
success: function(response) 
{
      if((response !== "") && ($.isNumeric(response))) {
        {
         //redirect in ajax success
         location.href = "http://localhost/manage/info.php?id="+ response;
        } 
      else {
             //this will display the custom error.
             $("#display_error").html("<p>" + response + "</p>"); //output: something went wrong!
           }
 }
```

**PHP**

```
$info = $_POST['info'];

if($info != 'Info Here') {
    $conn = mysqli_connect();
    $query = "INSERT INTO leads VALUES(0, '$companyName', 1, NOW(), 3)";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ('Error Could Not Query');

    $id = mysqli_insert_id($result);

    echo $id;

   //header("Location: http://localhost/manage/info.php?id=$id");

    mysqli_close($conn);
} else { 
    echo 'something went wrong!';
}
```